# How does WCF work in terms of a node.js/Nginx stack?

Tags: .net, wcf

My experience in creating 'web-service-like-apps' comes from the open source world where, for example, I'd setup Nginx to receive requests to my server and then either pass those requests to an application server - i.e. a reverse proxy in front of CouchDB or a node.js web server, or direct those request to locations on the server that contained html files, or PHP scripts, etc.

Using the approach described above it is very easy to set up an endpoint and deal with each endpoint on a case-by-case basis. So for example if I want to handle data from a sensor every 5 minutes to my endpoint of `https://example.com/sendSensorData`, I create a node.js app listening on port 9000, pass web requests to localhost:9000 via Nginx/Caddy/Apache/etc, then write node.js code to look for requests with the `sendSensorData` path and then write code to handle the data that I expect to arrive at that endpoint. Since I would be using HTTP I would use a node.js http library to actually make requests, which in turn handles specifics of the OSI stack similarly to .NET bindings (I think).

I get the point of WCF I think (in that in the long run it's easier to maintain, quicker to develop more complex systems, and probably has security benefits as well), but now I'm struggling to understand what a WCF web service is actually doing.

There is quite a lot of information on what WCF is from an abstracted point of view, but finding decent information on the specifics is less easy.

I have found material that mentions it is used to create APIs, configurable in terms of data-exchange formats, network protocols, and endpoint structure. i.e. that you can configure several endpoints easily to a single service in terms of

- Addresses that your service can be contacted on
- Bindings - i.e. OSI stuff such as transport protocols, encoding, SSL, etc
- Contracts... data format (JSON/XML), data structure (types), network responses? data-payload expectations, etc...

I understand that addresses and bindings are configured in an XML file called `App.Config`. In my specific case, this file is included in a console app, which kicks off long lived WCF processes (I think). In the config file, there are 4 `service` blocks and one `bindings` block. So I assume that there are four services all using the same bindings stack (I think it's pretty cool how you can define specifics of the OSI stack by configuration in .NET, if that is what the bindings directive allows for). And each service has it's own `behaviour` block (only spelt incorrectly as `behavior`).

I'm now trying to figure out contracts, which seems to involve decorating with attributes (classes, attributes, etc) and including project references in such a way that allows the .NET framework to build the endpoint for you without any additional work.

is this correct? Alternatively, what is a better way of comparing a simple node.js example as I mentioned above to a similar .NET WCF app?

Comment: What is the actual question? For one, there is no such thing as an OSI stack - that model was used pre-2000 to describe networks but was abandoned once all networks actually became TCP. That's reflected in Tannenbaum's books after 2000. WCF publishes SOAP services, ie HTTP endpoints, just like any other web server. The content follows the SOAP, WS* standards, just like any other SOAP compliant stack. Contracts etc are part of *SOAP*

Comment: Also, WCF can actually publish endpoints using a number of different mechanisms - named pipes, MSMQs, HTTP, etc. I think what you are probably looking for is "WebAPI", which is much simpler than WCF, and designed for quickly implemented REST-style HTTP webservices. Much more closely aligned with what you were previously using.

Comment: BTW node.js is essentially the same as WCF when it comes to HTTP services - just a web server, nothing to do with OSI. Different ways of implementing the same SOAP standards.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I really doubt that all networks are TCP... But aside from that, when you say 'SOAP standards', how does this tie in with the HTTP protocol? From what I understand, SOAP is a protocol that lies on top of HTTP - i.e. if you want to consume some web-service that uses HTTP, then SOAP is a good way of structuring your information. But it seems that it's entirely possible to use HTTP without SOAP. Specifically, what SOAP standards is node.js implementing?

Comment: Seems to me that a service that was REST-compliant wouldn't have to implement SOAP

Comment: @ZachSmith you are confusing different network models, different standards, different stacks, different communication technologies. HTTP in OSI is considered an [Application-level protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Examples) and yet it's the underlying protocol for SOAP and REST. REST doesn't have standards, while SOAP does, covering different levels. If something says it supports SOAP, it's supposed to implement the [WS-I Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile) standards at least. Implementation quality varies though